# 409 Conflict while uploading to pypiserver

Tags: python-poetry, pypiserver

I have set-up a local pypiserver with repo myrepo. Managed to publish a package there fine with poetry. However, after changing some packages in my poetry environment I get:

```
poetry publish -r myrepo


Publishing mypackage (0.1.0) to myrepo
 - Uploading mypackage-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl 100%

  UploadError

  HTTP Error 409: Conflict
```

Obviously there is already a package mypackage (0.1.0) there, but should this not just overwrite it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I missed that you need to explicitly specify that you can overwrite the package. Adding -o option does the trick.

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -v ~/.htpasswd:/data/.htpasswd pypiserver/pypiserver:latest -o -P .htpasswd packages
```

See -o in https://pypi.org/project/pypiserver/